# Can't resolve all parameters for Authentication Service (Angular 7)

Tags: angular

I've got the feeling I'm missing something very obvious.
When providing the AuthenticationService into my LoginComponent, I get the error saying it `can't resolve all parameters for AuthenticationService`.
From hints on similar posts here on Stackoverflow, I guess it has something to do with a circular dependency, but I don't know where mine would be.

**AuthenticationService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Injectable( { providedIn: 'root' } );
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {
  }

  logIn( email: string, password: string ): Observable<any> {
    const authKey = btoa( `${email}:${password}` );
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set( 'Authorization', `basic ${authKey}` );
    const params  = new HttpParams().set( 'username', email );
    return this.http.get( 'user', { headers, params } ).pipe( map( ( user: any ) => {
      if ( user ) {
        localStorage.setItem( 'currentUser', JSON.stringify( { user: { authKey } } ) );
      }
    } ) );
  }

  logOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem( 'currentUser' );
  }
}
```

If `HttpClient` is removed from the constructor is removed, it works. So it has something to do with that.
I have another Service that also uses the `HttpClient`, but at this point in the development, that service is not yet used.

The AuthenticationService is provided in the AppModule (which goes against my understanding of `providedIn: 'root'` which I thought would provide it automatically in the root so I wouldn't have to explicitly "provide" it. I get a static injected error if I don't).
I've tried switching it by providing it from within the component that is using the service, but to no avail.

Who can help me out here?
Please tell me if I need to provide some more code.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you forget to put `@` in front of `Injectable`? `@Injectable`

Comment: *facepalm*, that's exactly it. Now getting a static injected error, but I can move on from here. Thank you @yurzui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included HttpClientModule in the app module?

Comment: I hadn't. This solved my static injected error on HttpClient after I added the "@" in front of Injectable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, 
make sure that you imported `HttpClientModule`  in app.module if yes and you still have that error, remove `{ providedIn: 'root' }` 
and introduce it in the providers of everywhere (component,service,..) 
that you want to call this service.